# Убрать блокировку выделения текста

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.
Подскажите как обойти блокировку данного [типа](https://habrahabr.ru/post/18080/):

```
function preventSelection(element){
  var preventSelection = false;

  function addHandler(element, event, handler){
    if (element.attachEvent) 
      element.attachEvent('on' + event, handler);
    else 
      if (element.addEventListener) 
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
  }
  function removeSelection(){
    if (window.getSelection) { window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); }
    else if (document.selection && document.selection.clear)
      document.selection.clear();
  }
  function killCtrlA(event){
    var event = event || window.event;
    var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (sender.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i))
      return;

    var key = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (event.ctrlKey && key == 'A'.charCodeAt(0))  // 'A'.charCodeAt(0) можно заменить на 65
    {
      removeSelection();

      if (event.preventDefault) 
        event.preventDefault();
      else
        event.returnValue = false;
    }
  }

  // не даем выделять текст мышкой
  addHandler(element, 'mousemove', function(){
    if(preventSelection)
      removeSelection();
  });
  addHandler(element, 'mousedown', function(event){
    var event = event || window.event;
    var sender = event.target || event.srcElement;
    preventSelection = !sender.tagName.match(/INPUT|TEXTAREA/i);
  });

  // борем dblclick
  // если вешать функцию не на событие dblclick, можно избежать
  // временное выделение текста в некоторых браузерах
  addHandler(element, 'mouseup', function(){
    if (preventSelection)
      removeSelection();
    preventSelection = false;
  });

  // борем ctrl+A
  // скорей всего это и не надо, к тому же есть подозрение
  // что в случае все же такой необходимости функцию нужно 
  // вешать один раз и на document, а не на элемент
  addHandler(element, 'keydown', killCtrlA);
  addHandler(element, 'keyup', killCtrlA);
}
```

Хотел написать UserScript, но не знаю как :(
Если поможете написать скрипт то буду примного благодарен.

Comment: переопределить эту функцию на пустую, до ее использования

Answer (score 1):

Это статья (на хабре) 2007 года!!!

Я отключаю возможность выделения текста так (через css):

```
user-select:                none;
    -khtml-user-select:     none;
    -moz-user-select:       none;
    -ms-user-select:        none;
    -o-user-select:         none;
    -webkit-user-select:    none;
```

Вот ссылка на сайт, где ты можешь посмотреть совместимость с современными (и не очень) браузерами

https://caniuse.com/#search=user-select

не поддерживается только Opera Mini (вообще не знаю, что это такое - оно css почти не поддерживает)

**P.S.**

создай класс

```
.noselect {
    user-select:                none;
        -khtml-user-select:     none;
        -moz-user-select:       none;
        -ms-user-select:        none;
        -o-user-select:         none;
        -webkit-user-select:    none;
}
```

и добавляй его динамически к элементам, для которых хочешь отключить выделение текста, например

```
$(myelement).addClass('noselect');
```

Comment: Не работает, сайт на котором пытаюсь применить lit-era.com

Comment: не понял - вы ко внешнему сайту это применить хотите?

Comment: Я зашел на сайт через Chrome, запустил консоль разработчика (F12), выбрал в открывшемся окне "Elements". на теге <body> нажал правой кнопкой мыши, выбрал "Add attribute" и вставил строчку style="user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none; -ms-user-select: none; -o-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none;", тег стал <body style="...">

У меня все заработало! - ничего не выделялось

Что конкретно вы делали с тегами?

Comment: Там и так не выделяется, а мне надо чтобы выделялось :)

Comment: тогда я значит не правильно понял суть вопроса - можно для меня медленно и 2 раза - что требуется сделать конкретно, что хочется добиться?

Comment: Есть сайт на котором нельзя выделить и скопировать текст, соответственно нужно выделить и скопировать

Comment: просто на главной странице https://lit-era.com/ из хром у меня все копируется и выделяется за милую душу, поэтому я и не понял

Comment: Так вы поможете мне обойти блокировку?

Comment: @Izya12, давайте по шагам - в чем именно возникла трудность и где, на каком этапе и я постараюсь пошагово объяснить, если удобно - можете чат создать чтобы быстрее обсуждение шло у нас